ttkbootstrap FontDialog Cancel and Ok give same result
While trying to use the FontDialog class from ttkbootstrap I noticed that no matter what button I press (OK or Cancel) on the window that opens that allows to choose the font parameters, the result will be the same. A font object is passed regardless of user interaction to the FontDialog.result attribute.
This is the code I wrote responsible for creating the object, opening the dialog window and updating the test label that I created for debugging:
from tkinter import *
import ttkbootstrap as tb
from ttkbootstrap.dialogs.dialogs import FontDialog

# my function that opens the font dialog window and sets the test_label font according to chosen parameters
def open_font_dialog_window():
    fd = FontDialog()
    fd.show()
    if fd.result:
        test_label.config(font=fd.result)

# main window
window = tb.Window(themename='superhero')
window.title('Image Watermark')
window.geometry('1500x800')

# label with random text for testing of FontDialog
test_label = Label(window, text='Sample Text')
test_label.pack()

# font dialog window open from button
font_button = Button(window, text='Choose Font', command=open_font_dialog_window)
font_button.pack()

window.mainloop()

Sample Text before any changes
Font parameters dialog window with the OK and Cancel buttons
Sample Text after setting font size to 72 and pressing Cancel
Sample Text after re-opening the FontDialog window, choosing font size=9 and font family=System and pressing the OK button
I am unsure whether it is my lack of experience that is the issue or if there is an actual bug in the library, the latter seems less likely since I just started Python and the library is being used by other people from the statistics I saw in PyPi.
Using Python version 3.10.7
and ttkbootstrap version 1.10.1
I tried using print to check the value returned from fd.result, fd._on_cancel and fd._on_submit to see if they change depending on my actions. I also tried to find where in the library is fd.result updated but I found no reference of self.result = something (some Font object or anything at all).
I also tried manipulating the _on_cancel and _on_submit functions in the library but no change I made fixed it.
My expectation is that when pressing the OK button, the selected parameters will be applied to whichever widget I am trying to update (in this case a label) and when I pressing the Cancel button, the label will have no changes applied to it.

Thanks for the super fast response, edited as requested, you can obviously change the geometry of the window if it is too big/small as you see fit.

Have you checked what the value of fd.result is for each button press? Is it possible that the value returned when you cancel the window is still something 'truthy'?

It always returns font#, where # changes according to how many times the process ran before, i.e., it starts with 1,2,3 and goes on and on.
I tried printing the output for fd.result, fd._on_cancel and fd._on_submit with multiple different button presses, both OK and Cancel return an object for fd._on_submit and fd.result while fd._on_cancel will always return None.
This makes sense when going into those functions in the FontDialog class but I am unsure why pressing Cancel calls the fd._on_submit function

I apologize  if my post isn't clear, this is the very first time I post here, obviously I have a lot to learn.
I tried being as concise while still giving as much information as possible about the process. I was worried it would become too long to read.

Probably, it could be a bug I guess. I tried all the possible solutions, but didn't work

Thank you both for taking the time to look into it.
I did find a fix for it thanks to a suggestion on a different platform but that requires making changes to the library itself.

As said in the comment, it is an implementation bug of FontDialog.
However you can fix it by creating a custom class inheriting from FontDialog and override the _on_cancel() function:
class MyFontDialog(FontDialog):
    def _on_cancel(self):
        # execute the original _on_cancel()
        super()._on_cancel()
        # reset self._result which is set whenever a font is selected
        self._result = None

Then use this custom font dialog instead:
def open_font_dialog_window():
    fd = MyFontDialog()  # use custom font dialog
    fd.show()
    if fd.result:
        test_label.config(font=fd.result)


Thank you, this is very similar to the answer I got on a different platform, there the person created a new function and then replaced FontDialog's _on_cancel function with his using:
fd._on_cancel = on_cancel
Where on_cancel is simply the same function but with the added line that you also suggested.
With his approval I will try to make a PR to the library GitHub, hopefully this can help others as well
